# Как обойти ограничения памяти при работе с большой матрицей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У меня очень большой DataFrame и я не могу вычислить матрицу корреляций из-за нехватки памяти.

Пробовал в Pandas использовать корреляцию: `df.corr()` но она оказалась намного медленнее чем в NumPy и тоже вылетает с ошибкой.

Есть ли подходы для обхода ограничения памяти в работе с большой матрицей?

Вот пример кода, но внимание, он подтягивает файл 50 мб:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://st.storeland.ru/11/2425/769/big_df.csv', index_col=False) 
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
numpy_matrix = df.T.values
print("Делаю корреляцию и тут вылетает скрипт с ошибка о нехватке памяти")
np_crl = np.corrcoef(numpy_matrix)
```

P.S. Это лишь часть от основного DataFrame, но и на нем у меня комп вешается.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, у Вас должно всё работать. Не такие большие объёмы Вы используете. Попробуйте запускаться вне юпитера (если Вы его используете). Скорее всего проблема в том, что Вы не удалили NaN. Я их заполнил нулями (Можно удалить строки с этими значениями или поступить по Вашему усмотрению). Вот этот код у меня выполняется крайне быстро и без большого отъедания оперативы:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('big_df.csv')
df = df.T.iloc[1:]
df = df.fillna(0)

c = df.corr()
```

Также могу предложить Вам вычисление матрицы корелляций в лоб. Здесь не должно быть ничего затратного по памяти:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('big_df.csv')
df = df.T.iloc[1:]
df = df.fillna(0)

corr = np.zeros((df.shape[1], df.shape[1]))
for i, col_i in tqdm(enumerate(list(df.columns))):
    for j, col_j in enumerate(list(df.columns)):
        corr[i, j] = df[[col_i, col_j]].corr().values[0, 1]

fontsize = 18
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(corr, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.xticks(fontsize=fontsize)
plt.yticks(fontsize=fontsize)
plt.title('Heatmap', fontsize=fontsize)
plt.grid(True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализацию пандас, я не знаю, поскольку она спрятана в c-библиотеке *module pandas._libs.algos*. Но подозреваю, что там всё реализовано грамотно.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Но в вашем случае матрица корреляций вычисляется по меньшей стороне `66` векторов. А нужно вычислять длинные вектора, которых `45564`. Попробуйте убрать транспонирование в вашем коде `df = df.T.iloc[1:]`  и снова попробовать.

Comment: @Mavar так Вы же делаете ровно то же самое: `df.T.values`. Если Вы хотите считать корелляцию всех совсеми, то на выходе получите матрицу 45564x45564. Или, если в байтах, 45564х45564х8 байт ~ 15 ГБ. Ок, можно уменьшить размеры, не вычисляя вторую половину, но Всё равно Вы получите примерно то же самое. Учитывая то, что pandas тратит ещё сверх этого на свои внутренние нужны память, вы вряд ли влезете в оперативу.

Comment: @Mavar Разрешите понинтересоваться, Вам нужно точное значение матрицы? Или можно приближённое получить?

Comment: Вам принципиально сделать эту операцию именно с помощью pandas? Кажется, что Вы решаете либо задачу, которая Вам не нужна, либо решаете нужную задачу не теми методами.

Comment: да. Мне нужно найти из всего массива вектора с определенным порогом корреляции и получить их индексы. `df.T.values` я делал для numpy, он иначе распознает матрицу, поэтому приходится её переворачивать. Файл действительно будет большим и потому я ищу какой-то итеративный способ обработки. Может быть разбивать вычисления на какие-то ограниченные семплы, делать вычисление и записывать в файл. Понимаю что такой способ будет медленнее, но другого способа получить матрицу не вижу пока.

Comment: @Mavar подскажите, для чего Вам нужны все значения?

Comment: эта процедура лишь часть методики. Мне нужно вычленить максимально похожие вектора из всего массива. Эти вектора описывают свойства пользователей. Для таких пользователей в дальнейшем будут готовить некоторое воздействие.

Comment: @Mavar так у вас решение для прода? Или это разовая операция? Почему не использовать скалярное произведение?

Comment: немного не понял, как использовать скалярное произведение. Если вы предлагаете использовать на замену корреляции, то степень похожести, лучше чем у корреляции я не нашел. Корреляция лучше всего сообщает о схожести двух векторов.

Comment: Вы хотели расписать способ вычисления как посчитать корелляцию для случая больших данных. Можете помочь в решении этого вопроса? >> Я завтра распишу, как посчитать корелляцию для случая больших данных, как в этом примере. Это можно сделать стандартными утилитами, немного поколдовав

Comment: Ой, пардон. У меня из головы вылетело. Сделаю. Фактически, Вам нужен стохастический градиентный спуск. Он сходится к той оценке, которая Вам нужна. Постараюсь сделать

Comment: @Mavar извините, сейчас большой загруз. Я не могу написать ответ. Посмотрите в сторону стохастического градиентного спуска. Или, мы можем обсудить детально решение в чате

Answer (score 1):

@hedgehogues уже [объяснил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948958/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-corr-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-pandas#comment1581381_949133), что только лишь для хранения результата вам понадобится  около 15.5 GiB памяти (не учитывая памяти, необходимой для хранения исходного DataFrame'а):

```
In [22]: 45564 * 45564 * 8 / 1024**3
Out[22]: 15.467987179756165
```

Поэтому вам надо определиться что вы хотите получить на выходе. Возможно вам более подойдет итерационный подход с отсеиванием:

1. расчитываете корреляцию для пары столбцов
2. проверяете коэффициент корреляции и сразу принимаете решение что с ним делать
3. сохраняете только те значения, которые представляют интерес
4. в качестве индекса "интересных" коэффициентов корреляции можно использовать кортеж из имени столбцов, например: `(12, 1234)`
5. выбираем следующую пару столбцов и повторяем с шага `1.`

Чтобы найти коэффициент корреляции для пары столбцов можно воспользоваться [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html):

```
In [30]: from scipy.stats import pearsonr

In [31]: pearsonr(df['2'], df['3'])[0]
Out[31]: -0.13790794556727842
```

Comment: Я завтра распишу, как посчитать корелляцию для случая больших данных, как в этом примере. Это можно сделать стандартными утилитами, немного поколдовав

Answer (score 0):

Единственное, что можно посоветовать - увеличить память. У меня все получилось нормально, хоть и относительно долго - минут 15. На борту 16Гб оперативной памяти.

Comment: если я урежу файл в половину, то все работает нормально. Но настоящий файл, который нужно обсчитать, в десять раз больше. У меня столько памяти не влезет :). Должен же быть какой-то итеративный способ обработки датафрейма?!